# why selenium is not detecting certain tags

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape certain text from [this website](https://www.techwithtim.net/?s=test).

**Problem:** I can't get this particular text associated with `h1` or `a` tags (highlighted in the picture): "HTTP Methods -- Get & POST". But I can access `class`="entry-summary" and get it's text though. All I get is empty strings when I access the tags. WHY?

**Excerpt of html as image:**
[image]

**Relevant code**

```py
main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main"))
)
#print(main.text)
articles = main.find_elements_by_tag_name("article")
header.append(articles[0].find_element_by_tag_name("a").text)
```

**Minimum working Code**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from random import randint

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.techwithtim.net/?s=test"

## Driver setup and access title

path = "../dater/driver/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(url)

## Extract main from the new page and then headers

main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main"))
)
#print(main.text)
articles = main.find_elements_by_tag_name("article")
header.append(articles[0].find_element_by_tag_name("a").text)
print(header)
```

Comment: [This][https://stackoverflow.com/a/64340305/5986651] is similar. Suggestion is to use: `header.append(article.find_element_by_tag_name("a").get_attribute("textContent"))` instead of `header.append(articles[0].find_element_by_tag_name("a").text)`. But I don't understand why selenium doesn't get this via `.text`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to get elements using

`.get_attribute('href')`

like:

```
header.append(articles[0].find_element_by_tag_name("a").get_attribute('href'))
print(header)
```

Hope this helps, seem to work for me.

Comment: I don't need `href`. I need `textContent`. This works.

Answer (score 0):

Is the content visible on screen? Or do you need to scroll down to access it? It could be out of reach, and in that case you would need to add a function that would scroll down for you such as:

```
main.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 10000)")
```

Comment: It's not visible as in I can't see it. But the webpage has loaded it. The text is in white and in a white background (looks like). I can hover over the text. I tried your script, it turns out that it doesn't output my headers anymore. Not sure why.